# Rails - Send associated form only if condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models: one for contacts ("Contatos") and one for users ("Usuarios"). Contatos `has_one` Usuario , as follows:

```
   class Contato < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :usuario, dependent: :destroy          
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :usuario,
                                    allow_destroy: true
```

And

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :contato

  validates_presence_of :login, :password
  validates_uniqueness_of :login

end
```

I want to use one form for creating and editing both models. The _form partial that I currently have is this:

```
 <%= form_with(model: contato, local: true) do |contato_form| %>
    <%= if contato.errors.any?
      showferr contato
     end %>


      #Here are the inputs for contato, I cut them out so it wouldn't be too long to read.
```

Bellow (same file as above) there is a check box for the `Contato` model that I left on, it sets a `Boolean` in the model(and DB) telling if the contact has a user on not, additionally I use some `JavaScript (Coffee)` to `toggle` the whole user `(Usuario)` form part based on the checkboxe's value .

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= contato_form.label :possui_usuario, :class => 'inline-checkbox' do %>
          Possui usuário
        <%= contato_form.check_box :possui_usuario, {id: "hasUser", checked: @contato.possui_usuario} %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="userPart" class="findMe" <% unless @contato.possui_usuario  %> style="display:none;" <% end %> >
      <h2> Usuário: </h2>
      <div class="container">
        <%= contato_form.fields_for :usuario, @contato.usuario do |usuario_form| %>
          <%= render partial: 'usuarios/campos_usuario', locals: {form: usuario_form, object: @contato} %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="container-fluid text-right">
      <%= contato_form.submit 'Confirmar', :class => 'btn-lg btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The partial form for the Usuario model is rendering ok, but what I want to do is to only create and/or validate the user part if the checkbox is selected (if I say that the contact does have a user).

Here's what I attempted last (there were many attempts):

At `Contato` model:

```
attr_accessor(:has_user)
  @has_user = 0
  before_validation do |record|
    @has_user = record.possui_usuario
  end

  def self.user?
    @has_user == 1
  end


  validates_presence_of :nome
  validates_length_of :nome, in: 1..45
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, with: email_regex
  validates_associated :usuario, if: user?
```

Controller for `Contato`:

```
class ContatosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contato, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contatos
  # GET /contatos.json
  def index
    @contatos = Contato.all
    @page_title = 'Contatos'
  end

  # GET /contatos/1
  # GET /contatos/1.json
  def show
    @page_title = 'Ver contato: ' + @contato.nome
  end

  # GET /contatos/new
  def new
    @contato = Contato.new
    @contato.build_usuario
    @contato.ativo = true
    @page_title = 'Novo contato'
  end

  # GET /contatos/1/edit
  def edit
    @page_title = 'Editar contato: ' + @contato.nome
    unless @contato.possui_usuario
      @contato.build_usuario
    end
  end

  # POST /contatos
  # POST /contatos.json
  def create
    @contato = Contato.new(contato_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contato.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Contato foi criado com sucesso.'
        format.html {redirect_to @contato}
        format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @contato}
      else
        flash[:warn] = "Erro ao criar contato."
        format.html {render :new}
        format.json {render json: @contato.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contatos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contatos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contato.update(contato_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @contato, notice: 'Contato foi atualizado com sucesso.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @contato}
      else
        format.html {render :edit}
        format.json {render json: @contato.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contatos/1
  # DELETE /contatos/1.json
  def destroy
    @contato.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to contatos_url, notice: 'Contato deletado com sucesso.'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_contato
    @contato = Contato.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def contato_params
    params.require(:contato).permit(:id, :empresa_id,
                                    :ativo, :nome,
                                    :cargo, :celular,
                                    :email, :nascimento,
                                    :observacoes, :mensagem_instantanea,
                                    :tipo_msg_inst, :possui_usuario,
                                    usuario_attributes: [:login, :password, :permissoes, :id, :contato_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

Sorry for the long question and big code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I see two holes in the data presented currently ...

First, your controller action where `create` is called is where you should be testing to see if you are calling to the model / activerecord.

Something like ...

```
def create
  if @contato && @contato.usuarios    # might be able to just do last half
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contato = @contato.create!(contato_params)    # note the bang or '!'
          format.html { redirect_to @contato, notice: 'contato was successfully created.' }
        else
          format.html { render :new } 
        end
      end
    end 
  end
```

Without seeing your controller - I am going to guess you didn't nest your controller via [Rails strong_param](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) feature properly.  Note here - these two won't run, I'm not quite sure what information is needed, but I wanted you to make sure if you are nesting your models and using a single controller - you are away you need to nest your models in strong_params (google search nested rails strong_params for thousands of help / hits).

```
params.require(:contato).permit(:login, :password, usuario: [id, ...] )
```

If that's not it - also tell us if all the functionality of create/read/update/destroy works normally & you are just looking to limit it to create in certain circumstances?

---

Update - based on the controller - just move your check for create from the model & move it to the controller at the start of the `#create` action ... maybe start with ...

```
def create
  # Note - here you will have to inspect contato_params to find syntax
  if contato_params[:usuario_attributes][:contato_id]
    ... rest of action wrapped in here ...
  end
end
```

... once again ... you will need to work out exact syntax - but just like you did with the edit - this spot is where you control the creation - not in the model.

---

More specifically I see this `@contato.possui_usuario` in the form ... that's probably the variable you want to check against in your controller, but perhaps my suggestion is more important - I can't tell you that with certainty - I'm also not sure you need the `has_user` trick per say in model & might be tempted to do a controller version in the private method section ...

```
class ContatosController
  private
    def has_user?
       ... whatever ...
    end
```

---

Clarification from comment:

> If I move the control over the user form part to the controller (which
>   makes a lot of sense) how would I about canceling the
>   validates_associated part of the model in case the user decides that
>   this contact wont have any users?

You don't move the form control (defined as variable in the form), you move the model method that deals with the form control to the controller - then you can wrap it all in a transaction to rollback any other changes OR if you build your activerecord out with #build it will do it for you.

Comment: Adding the controller, I totally forgot, oops. And Please explain to me the `@dcontato` was it a typo? What is it?

Comment: None of the syntax is going to be exactly right.  I won't be making a mirror project alongside you just providing some insight in places I have questions.

Comment: Still, I have a question: If I move the control over the user form part to the controller (which makes  a lot of sense) how would I about canceling the `validates_associated` part of the model in case the user decides that this contact wont have any users?